# Breaking up data and finding independence

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have  the list with elements (either 1 or 4 as the last digit)
as follows:

```
data=
{{42, 49.11, 1}, {41, 49.32, 4}, {41, 48.21, 4}, {41, 53.08, 1}, {39, 
  46.22, 1}, {39, 47.06, 1}, {47, 48.87, 4}, {41, 49.64, 1}, {41, 
  48.44, 1}, {42, 49.98, 4}, {39, 49.04, 1}, {46, 48.73, 1}, {49, 
  48.33, 4}, {39, 50.95, 1}, {42, 46.05, 4}, {49, 52.52, 1}, {49, 
  48.81, 1}, {49, 50.75, 4}, {47, 52.39, 1}, {41, 52.56, 1}, {40, 
  56.01, 4}, {46, 52.77, 4}, {43, 52.81, 1}, {39, 50.37, 1}, {40, 
  52.38, 1}, {49, 51.31, 4}, {48, 54.26, 4}, {40, 53.3, 4}, {42, 
  50.62, 4}, {48, 49.66, 4}, {43, 51.39, 4}, {41, 59.23, 4}, {41, 
  49.07, 4}, {40, 51.43, 4}, {39, 54.47, 4}, {49, 50.4, 4}, {48, 
  51.04, 1}, {46, 47.95, 1}, {45, 50.52, 4}, {44, 53.18, 1}}
```

How do I break it into two sets with the same last digit,
such that

```
data1={{42, 49.11, 1},  {41, 53.08, 1}, {39, 
  46.22, 1}, {39, 47.06, 1}, {41, 49.64, 1}, {41, 
  48.44, 1}, {39, 49.04, 1}, {46, 48.73, 1}, {39, 50.95, 1}, 
 {49, 52.52, 1}, {49, 48.81, 1}...}
```

and

```
data2={{41, 49.32, 4}, {41, 48.21, 4}, {47, 48.87, 4},{42, 49.98, 4}, {49, 
  48.33, 4},  {42, 46.05, 4}, {49, 50.75, 4},  {40,   56.01, 4}, {46, 52.77, 4}..}
```

How do I test whether these two data sets are linearly independent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is just:

```
GatherBy[data, Last]
```

For easy manipulation you might use this:

```
ruleData= #[[1, -1]] -> # & /@ GatherBy[data, Last];
```

Then get the part you want with e.g.:

```
4 /. ruleData
```

> ```
> {{41, 49.32, 4}, {41, 48.21, 4}, {47, 48.87, 4}, . . .}
> ```

You'll have to explain in more detail what you mean by:

> How do I test whether these two data sets are linearly independent?

Comment: @Wizard GatherBy command does not break up the list into 2 distinct lists, which will be convenient for later manipulations. By independence, I mean possibility of Pearson Correlation Tests etc.

Comment: thils, it now sounds like you mean *statistical* independence, not *linear* independence. The two are entirely different things! Also, if you want something "convenient for later manipulations," you really ought to specify what procedures you have in mind--please don't make us guess. Edit your question to clarify what you need.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I am after statistical independence, apologies. "later manipulations" is for determining mean, median & performing error analysis on the extracted data lists.